# Guice: How to get instance of Singleton without injector or using Constructor Injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have got an singleton class defined as:

```
@Singleton
class MySingletonClass{
   ....
}
```

I have another class which uses this singleton Class but this class has to be created using new operator. Thus I cannot use constructor injection or setter injection etc.

```
class MyClass {
   public void method() {
       // Uses instnace of MySingletonClass
   }
}
```

I can certainly pass an instance of this into the constructor of MyClass but it does not quite a good design from the context of my program.

Another solution will be to create an static getInstance method for MySingletonClass so that I can get instance from anywhere in the program. But I want to know if Guice supports anything similar to this? I am sure Guice can allow getting singleton instance anywhere.

Many thanks.

Comment: *I am sure Guice can allow getting singleton instance anywhere.* Guice is a DI container, so it allows magic to happen, but only inside the conainer, and this container is `Injector` instance. You have to access it, implicitly (from inside the container, via constructor injection for example) or explicitly (`getInstance()` method). Consequently, you have to either put your class under DI control or pass your dependencies through manually. First solution is obviously better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Injector instance should be created once globally in the application in the very top level (e.g. main method). But is there any ways I can get the Injector instance anywhere in the app without explicitly pass the instance created in the main method down to all the classes?

Comment: No, there are not. `Injector`, after all, is a simple object. BTW, there can be more than one injector, and they can form a hierarchy. Which one should be available in the whole program then? The only way you can get `Injector` instance without passing it explicitly is injecting it into one of the managed classes.

Answer (score 4):

I think that if myClass needs the MySingletonClass, this means that there is a clear dependency between them, and hence a correct solution is to pass the instance of MySingletonClass to the constructor of MyClass.

The constructor injection is one of the the most desirable injection methods since it makes the dependency explicit and prevent the creation of MyClass with unsatisfied dependencies.
If you really don't like the constructor injection, you can always use a setter injection where you can manually inject the instance of MySingletonClass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The design of my code prohibit of passing an instance of MySingltonClass to MyClass. Also, I want to know if I can use Guice's injector anywhere? If so, I can simply call injector.getInstance(MySingletonClass.class).

Comment: It's funny, but Guice really allows getting an injector, but it has to be *injected* too, like any other dependency. If you *really* cannot change your code to use dependency injection, then your best bet will be passing your singleton manually to the instantiated class. If this class depends on more than only this singleton, you can try [on-demand injection](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections#On-demand_Injection) instead.